# What is the reason behind deconstruction of function arguments in Flux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to Flux and I wonder why argument deconstruction is so frequent.
It creates a lot of noise for beginner, so I hope it's for a reason.

For example, something like this seems excessive at first glance:

```
function incrementIfOdd() {
  return (
    dispatch: (action: actionType) => void,
    getState: () => counterStateType
  ) => {
      const { counter } = getState();

      if (counter % 2 === 0) {
        return;
      }

      dispatch(increment());
  };
}
```

Also: How should I know if I should return an object or anonymous function like in code above?

Found at:
https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/actions/counter.js#L23

I used babeljs.io/repl/ to "translate" it in order to [understand what this does](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Ces2015%2Ces2015-loose%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDSAnApgW3WKBJYAeQBNiAKASkQG8AoRRDKEVJM4mAZwAcBDKCAAsAXIjK9o8MKImwEAFQCe3dFQC8APkQA3ODGIAaRAHN0UAMpR-6UZUSbEEOOCjpUl60pXqtdBgycwTigaR2dcN0QAX3sTMw9XSgBuWnp_GGAxJxdIgFJEACZ7NTVEAAYqP38GJhYwFOqo1OqOHn4hMhQIDGxcSgoG6JSmoA).

Comment: Syntactic sugar I would guess. They are [setting default params](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) in the return function. Makes defensive coding easier. And as we all know, it's "cool" to write bleeding edge code!

Comment: Without destructuring, you have to write lots of extra code just to access properties of objects.

Comment: once you get used to it it's easier to read

Answer (score 1):

None of the syntax in there is Flux (or Redux) specific:

- The notations after `dispatch` and `getState` are type notations, presumably either for Flow or TypeScript
- The `const { counter }` usage is an ES6 "destructuring assignment", and is a shorter way of saying `const counter = getState().counter`

With Redux, it's common to write "action creator" functions.  Normal action creators return an action (a plain object with a `type` field).  It's also common to write "thunk action creators", which return a function that can contain asynchronous logic or access the store like in the example you pasted.